# Changing git history commit messages

Tags: ruby, git, git-filter-branch

I would like to change the git history for my repository before I bring in other team members to repository.

I know I can run a git filter-branch like

`git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'ruby -e "puts ARGF.read.capitalize"' -- --all`

There are a few issues with the above command though.  I would like to capitalize the first letter for each line that isn't a symbol.  The above code only capitalizes the first line for the whole commit message, I'd like to apply this to each line in the commit.

How can I do this using a command similar to above?  I understand that I would need to rebase when this is complete.  What is the recommended way to push this to the remote origin server as well?

I know that this generally isn't recommended however I am the only person using the repository at the moment so I'd like to tidy this up before others are given access.

Comment: `ARGF.readlines.map(&:capitalize).join($/)` it is safe to call `capitalize` on each line, since symbols will be left intact.

Comment: @mudasobwa That is very close, it is replacing an empty line with two lines though (i.e. it's adding a new empty line at the end of every line).  Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: It does not replace empty lines with anything. It works exactly as expected. Please give an example of input file on which you experience empty line doubling.

Comment: @mudasobwa It worked for me if I just used ARGF.readlines.map(&:capitalize)

Comment: OK, fine, though it is strange :)

Comment: I also had to run `git push origin --force branch` and `git push origin --force --tags` to push to the remote, then make all clients resync.  If you'd like to type up an answer to this then I will accept it @mudasobwa

Comment: The main part of the answer was done by you, so I would suggest you to write the answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: @Luke like you said, it is best not to rewrite history. Git has a command to rewrite the message of the latest commit made, but no further. Doing so, even for one commit, recreates the hash (alphanumeric value) associated with the commit, _as well as the date and time submitted_. Your commit messages will not be scrutinized, as they only _help_ when figuring out how the changes are associated with each other.